# How to define several Texts and put them out randomly?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a GameOverText Label.

```
    gameoverText = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"MarkerFelt-Thin"];
    gameoverText.fontColor = [SKColor grayColor];
    gameoverText.fontSize = 25;
    gameoverText.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+ CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)/1.6);
    gameoverText.zPosition = 4;
    gameoverText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game Over!"];
    [self addChild:gameoverText];
```

Now I want to write somewhere several texts. E.g. 1."You Lose", 2."Game Over", 3."Try Again", 4."Maybe Next Time".

How can I define this texts and call them randomly in my GameOverText Label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gameoverText = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"MarkerFelt-Thin"];
gameoverText.fontColor = [SKColor grayColor];
gameoverText.fontSize = 25;
gameoverText.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+ CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)/1.6);
gameoverText.zPosition = 4;

int r0 = arc4random() % 4
switch (r0)
{
    case 0:
        gameoverText.text = @"You lose";
        break;
    case 1:
        gameoverText.text = @"Game over";
        break;
    case 2:
        gameoverText.text = @"Try again";
        break;
    case 3:
        gameoverText.text = @"Maybe next time";
        break;
    default:
        gameoverText.text = @"You lose";
        break;
    }
}
[self addChild:gameoverText];
```